# Programmably set currency format to field in access 2010 form?

Tags: forms, format, ms-access-2010

I have an access 2010 table with order line detail which includes a field with the price and a separate field for the currency type.  That currency type field currently only supports "USD" or "EUR".   When the record is shown on a form, I'd like to have the price field format automatically use either Currency or Euro (in design view this can be set manually via property sheet) based on the currency type field.  How is that done?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Format will do that, either set as property of a textbox ("Currency") or by an expression:

```
=Format(123.45, "Currency")
```